# XmlWriter.WriteElementString fails to write Base64 string

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm writing a tool to encode a .pdf as a base64 string, and insert it into an XML element. When I test it across different .pdf files, I find that in some cases it works as expected, while in others it simply does not insert the base64 string.

```
$xmlObjectSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlObjectSettings.Indent = $true 
$xmlObjectSettings.IndentChars = "    "
$xmlFilePath = $Path
$xmlObjectWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($xmlFilePath,$xmlObjectSettings)
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteStartElement("Report","http://www.website.com/ns")
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteStartElement("pdfFile")
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteElementString("Data","$base64EncodedString")
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteEndElement()
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteEndElement()
$xmlObjectWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlObjectWriter.Flush()
$xmlObjectWriter.Close()
$xmlObjectWriter.Dispose()
```

When I check during debugging, I see the $base64EncodedString value is present both in cases where it gets populated into the XML and when it fails. When it fails, the "Data" element is entirely missing. I know its a broad question, but I'm hoping someone can provide some insight as to why this would be failing on certain encoded .pdf files vs. others.

Comment: Could be the `$base64EncodedString` has invalid characters. You can try writing that as CDATA instead

Comment: You're missing at least one call to `$xmlObjectWriter.WriteEndElement()`

Comment: Tried $xmlObjectWriter.WriteCdata($base64EncodedString), similarly did not populate the string in the CDATA node. Also, added the missing $xmlObjectWriter.WriteEndElement() for clarity, but this doesn't seem to have been the issue.

Comment: After some further testing, I noticed if I read the file into memory and access the "pdfFile" element, that it actually does show the "Data" node and it does contain the expected base64 encoded pdf file... but the "Data" node is not visible in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Was just a display issue with the XML reader I was using (internet explorer). The data is present as expected when opened in notepad.